# How to run jobs in parallel through tcsh script?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, scripting, tcsh

Consider a tcsh script with the below code,

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

set PWD = $PWD

if (!a) then
  mkdir a
  cd a
  ln -sfn temp.txt
endif 
cd $PWD/a
job << END
# some tool specific settings
END
```

Now,

1. I need to do the same for two other directories, say b & c, through the same script.
2. I want all the three to run in parallel.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: [Why would you use csh for anything actually *important*?](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

Comment: I think the `tcsh`-script isn't the better solution. I don't know what is your *exact* problem but I would do it with `make` (to create files/directories if they aren't exist).

Comment: Can you please suggest how to do it through make?

Comment: If you want to do the same thing three times but each time with a different directory, you should probably use a shell like `bash` which supports functions with variable parameters. Presumably, given that directory creation is near instant, you want to exploit parallelism to speed up whatever the job is at the end. Maybe consider **GNU Parallel** for that.

Comment: If the basic script works for one dir then why not accept a command line arg that is the directory you are interested in.  Use that to "parameterize" the script above.  Then write a wrapper script that calls the one above and passes in the dir names.  When calling each sub-script you would end it with an `&` to run it in the background.

Comment: `env_parallel.csh` is a non-trivial program written in `csh`. Due to its nature it _had_ to be written in `csh`. As the author I can tell you it was a nightmare, so I have to agree with @CharlesDuffy: Do not use `(t)csh` unless you _really_ cannot use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

just add "&" here

```
job << END
```

i.e

```
job << END &
# some tool specific settings
END
```

But beware that the output from "# some tool specific settings" from all the multiple jobs will all be printed together and will be messy. Smart thing is to redirect each job's output to its own file

```
job >> job_output.out << END &
# some tool specific settings
END
```

The hardcoded file name "job_output.out" above is okay, since you do a cd into different directories each time and so job_output.out will be different file for each job.